# Rotate object Several times slowly Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I want to rotate smoothly on its Y axis several times, the RotateCount (number of times the object rotate on itself) is a variable, so I can change it to the number I want. I wrote the code below below but the object rotate only once? how can I fix that please?

```
public IEnumerator RotateObject()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);
    RotateCount = 5;
    float Yrot = 360f;
    float t = 0;
    float targetRot = 0;
    Vector3 eulers = object.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    while (targetRot < Yrot)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        targetRot = Mathf.Lerp(targetRot, Yrot * RotateCount, t * (0.3f * RotateCount));
        object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulers.x, targetRot, eulers.z);
        yield return null;
    }
    object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulers.x, Yrot, eulers.z);
}
```

Comment: er repeat it until its got back to 0 > times wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rotates only once, because your `Yrot` variable is set to `360f` which causes the Coroutine to stop after one turn. Instead of multiplying it in the line where you set the `targetRot` variable in your `while` loop, you may want to use it as an exit condition and maybe either multiply it in the `while` loop head with `Yrot` or do that above, so you only need to do it once, like so:

```
public IEnumerator RotateObject()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);
    RotateCount = 5;
    float Yrot = 360f * RotateCount;
    float t = 0;
    float targetRot = 0;
    Vector3 eulers = object.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    while (targetRot < Yrot)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        targetRot = Mathf.Lerp(targetRot, Yrot, t * (0.3f * RotateCount));
        object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulers.x, targetRot, eulers.z);
        yield return null;
    }
    object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulers.x, Yrot, eulers.z);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works now, but it always rotate in the same time, I mean if it's 1, it rotate 1 time in 1 second, and if it's 5, it rotate 5 times in 1 seconds! how can I change the time also, so it rotate 5 times in 5 seconds, 8 times in 8 seconds etc...?

Comment: You can do so, by removing the `RotateCount` multiplication where you use the `Mathf.Lerp` call. This will make it run one second per rotation.